# SQL get first available date before 'xxxx-xx-xx'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a query to get the first available date moving backwards excluding unavailable dates. 
**Example:**
Date must be before `2016-05-20`(this date is a variable). Best choice is `2016-05-19`(first day before). If this is not available, then get day earlier.
Unavailable dates are saved in a table and can be selected like this
 `SELECT blockedDate FROM tbl_BlockedDates`

EDIT:
I have seen that something like this would work but I can't figure out how to set it up correctly for my situation

```
 SELECT TOP 1 [Date]
            FROM (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @Date1, @Date2)+1)
        [Date] = dateadd(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c1.name), @Date1)
        FROM  [master].[dbo].[spt_values] c1 
            ) D 
            WHERE D.Date NOT IN (SELECT ClosingDate FROM ClosingDays WHERE IsClosedAllDay = 1) 
            and Date not in (SELECT blockedDate FROM tbl_BlockedDates )
```

How can I get the date that I need?

Comment: Do you have a date dimension / calendar table available to you?

Comment: Use a numbers table to create a calendar, and left join it with the blocked dates table.

Answer (score 4):

You need a date table to this

```
Declare @start_date datetime = '2014-01-01', 
        @varibale_date datetime = '2016-05-20'

;WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), -- 10
e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b), -- 10*10
e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2), -- 10*100
e4(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e3 CROSS JOIN e2), 
Tally(n) AS (select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM e4),
dates(dt) AS (select DATEADD(dd,n-1,@start_date) from tally)
SELECT TOP 1 dt 
FROM   dates 
WHERE  dt < @varibale_date 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_blockeddates t 
                       WHERE  t.blockeddate = dt) 
ORDER  BY dt DESC
```

Comment: Can you do this using `sys_objects` to create the table. see example query in question

Answer (score 2):

This is more complicated than it sounds, because you might have a chain of blocked dates and have to get the day before it.

It is simple enough if there are no blocked dates or if the blocked dates have a gap before the date in question:

```
with bd as (
      select bd.*, max(grp) as maxgrp
      from (select bd.*,
                   dateadd(day, - row_number() over (order by blockeddate), blockeddate) as grp
            from tbl_BlockedDates bd
            where blockedDate < @Date
           ) bd
     )
select (case when max(blockedDate) is null or
                  max(blockedDate) <> dateadd(day, -1, @Date)
             then dateadd(day, -1, @Date)
             else dateadd(day, -1, min(case when grp = maxgrp then blockedDate end))
        end) as FreeDate
from bd;
```

The `else` part is the tricky part.  `grp` defines a group of consecutive dates.  The `min()` is getting the first date of such a group and subtracting on day.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @DateVariable DATE = '20160520';

SELECT  TOP (1) 
        YT.yourDate 
FROM    yourTable AS [YT] 
WHERE   YT.yourDate < @DateVariable
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_BlockedDate AS [bd] WHERE bd.blockedDate = YT.yourDate)
ORDER BY 
    YT.yourDate DESC;
```

An issue here is that you haven't given us your DDL statements for your calendar table (*If you don't have one, then Zohar Peled makes a great point and solution to this in the comments of your question*).

---

However, if you do have a calendar table or a table with dates in it, you may want to be wary of multiple entries in there with the same date that are not present in your `tbl_BlockedDate` table.

**Example**

```
ID  |  Date         |
---------------------
1   | '2016-05-20'  |
2   | '2016-05-19'  |
3   | '2016-05-19'  |
4   | '2016-05-19'  |
5   | '2016-05-19'  |
```

The above query will return 1 row with a date of the 19th but multiple rows satisfy the query.

If you change the query to include `WITH TIES`, it will return all 4 records with the 19th as they all satisfy this query.

```
SELECT  TOP (1) WITH TIES
        YT.yourDate 
FROM    yourTable AS [YT] 
WHERE   YT.yourDate < @DateVariable
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_BlockedDate AS [bd] WHERE bd.blockedDate = YT.yourDate)
ORDER BY 
    YT.yourDate DESC;
```

That is why it's recommended to include another identifying column in your order by to *hopefully* eliminate this issue.

The below example uses the made up column `ID` to return the row with a `Date: '2016-05-19'` and an `ID: 2`.

```
SELECT  TOP (1) 
            YT.yourDate 
    FROM    yourTable AS [YT] 
    WHERE   YT.yourDate < @DateVariable
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_BlockedDate AS [bd] WHERE bd.blockedDate = YT.yourDate)
    ORDER BY 
        YT.yourDate DESC,
        YT.identifying_column ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who took time to respond. By combining all answers, this is what worked for me.

```
DECLARE @date = '2016-05-16'
SELECT TOP 1 [Date]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 120 
    [Date] = dateadd(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c1.name), @date)
    FROM  [master].[dbo].[spt_values] c1 
) D 
WHERE D.Date  NOT IN (select blockedDate from tbl_BlockedDates)
```

By using the negative `-ROW_NUMBER()`, I created a table of dates decreasing from the date passed in. I joined to the `Tbl_blockedDates` to exclude those dates from the table.
Then I selected the `TOP[1]` to get the first available date.

Comment: this is really overkill.. check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a simple recursive cte without any extra tables..

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, @StartDate) [Start]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, [Start]) 
    FROM   cte
    INNER JOIN @tbl_BlockedDates ON cte.[Start] = blockedDate
)
SELECT MIN([Start]) FROM cte
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/8112)

Comment: How can I do this with more than one table of blocked days?

Comment: easiest way would be to just select the blocked dates into a single table or cte using `UNION`..  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb280/1

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_BlockedDates](
    [BlockedDate] [date] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_BlockedDates]([BlockedDate]) VALUES ('2016-05-16');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_BlockedDates]([BlockedDate]) VALUES ('2016-05-15');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_BlockedDates]([BlockedDate]) VALUES ('2016-05-14');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_BlockedDates]([BlockedDate]) VALUES ('2016-05-12');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_BlockedDates]([BlockedDate]) VALUES ('2016-05-11');

  Declare @MyDate as Date , @CheckDate as date, @BestDate as Date

  Set @MyDate = '2016-05-16';
  Set @CheckDate = '2016-05-16';

  while (@BestDate is null)
  Begin
    Set @CheckDate = DateAdd(day,-1,@CheckDate)
    If  NOT Exists (Select 1 from tbl_BlockedDates where BlockedDate = @CheckDate)
        begin
            Select @BestDate = @CheckDate
        end
    END


    Select @BestDate as BestDate
```

Comment: This will be efficient - especially if the blockedDate field is indexed or is the primary key of the tbl_BlockedDates table.

Comment: Its hard to evaluate with only a few rows.  The cte example may end up being better.  To test you can Set Statistics Time On and Set Statistics io On prior to execution of the code.  This will return time elapsed in milliseconds and the cpu usage.  Remember to turn these back off....